# MySQL - Group by Price - Count Distinct

Tags: mysql

I have a `product_outer` table which contains prices.  I'd like to group by price and then count.  The following code works for all products within category "8":

```
SELECT price_range, count(*) AS num
FROM
(SELECT CASE

 WHEN po.price >= 0 AND po.price < 10 THEN '0.00 - 9.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 10 AND po.price <= 20 THEN '10.00 - 19.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 20 AND po.price <= 30 THEN '20.00 - 29.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 30 AND po.price <= 40 THEN '30.00 - 39.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 40 AND po.price <= 50 THEN '40.00 - 49.99'
 ELSE '50+'

 END as price_range

FROM product_category pc INNER JOIN product_outer po ON pc.product_outer_id = po.id
WHERE pc.category_id = '8' AND po.active = '1'
) AS  price_summaries
GROUP BY price_range
```

It gives the following result:

```
price_range       num
=====================
10.00 - 19.99     1
20.00 - 29.99     1
30.00 - 39.99     1
```

I need to take this one step further.  Each `product_outer` can have multiple `product_inner` records.  I may need to include `product_inner` data in the WHERE clause, however when I introduce this table, the count goes haywire:

```
SELECT price_range, count(*) AS num
FROM
(SELECT CASE

 WHEN po.price >= 0 AND po.price < 10 THEN '0.00 - 9.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 10 AND po.price <= 20 THEN '10.00 - 19.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 20 AND po.price <= 30 THEN '20.00 - 29.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 30 AND po.price <= 40 THEN '30.00 - 39.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 40 AND po.price <= 50 THEN '40.00 - 49.99'
 ELSE '50+'

 END as price_range

FROM product_category pc INNER JOIN product_outer po ON pc.product_outer_id = po.id INNER JOIN product_inner pi ON pi.product_outer_id = po.id INNER JOIN product_attribute pa ON pa.product_inner_id = pi.id
WHERE pc.category_id = '8' AND po.active = '1'
) AS  price_summaries
GROUP BY price_range
```

(Note the different FROM line)

The output is as follows:

```
price_range       num   
=====================
10.00 - 19.99     10
20.00 - 29.99     6
30.00 - 39.99     6
```

I only want to count distinct po.ID's... how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT price_range, count(distinct id) AS num
FROM
(SELECT po.id, CASE

 WHEN po.price >= 0 AND po.price < 10 THEN '0.00 - 9.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 10 AND po.price <= 20 THEN '10.00 - 19.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 20 AND po.price <= 30 THEN '20.00 - 29.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 30 AND po.price <= 40 THEN '30.00 - 39.99'
 WHEN po.price >= 40 AND po.price <= 50 THEN '40.00 - 49.99'
 ELSE '50+'

 END as price_range

FROM product_category pc INNER JOIN product_outer po ON pc.product_outer_id = po.id INNER JOIN product_inner pi ON pi.product_outer_id = po.id INNER JOIN product_attribute pa ON pa.product_inner_id = pi.id
WHERE pc.category_id = '8' AND po.active = '1'
) AS  price_summaries
GROUP BY price_range
```